# Function to construct binary decision tree

Tags: f#

Suppose I have the following tree structure:

```
type Tree =
  | Branch of (string*string) * (Tree*Tree)
  | Leaf of float
```

For example, it could look something like this:

```
Branch (("X1",">4.5"), (Branch (("X2",">4.5"), (Leaf 3.4, Leaf 5.5)), Branch (("X3",">4.5"), (Leaf 6.5, Leaf 4.5))))
```

What would be the essential parts of a function to create a tree like this (from data, randomly, or whatever)?
I know my question is similar to [how to make a tree from a given data with F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647591/how-to-make-a-tree-from-a-given-data-with-f), but I'm having the hardest time translating to my tree.

Edit: I'm trying to build a decision tree, and I started with the tree [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2009/11/02/awesome-f-decision-trees-part-ii.aspx) which looks like this:

```
type DecisionTreeNode = 
  // Attribute name and value / child node list 
  | DecisionNode of string * (string * DecisionTreeNode) seq 
  // Decision and corresponding evidence 
  | Leaf of bool * Record seq
```

However, mine is a regression tree, so it should have leafs of float, and I only want binary splits, so I thought I could use tuple instead of seq for the nodes.
After looking at that tree again, I'm wondering if mine should look like this:

```
type Tree = 
  | Branch of string*((string*Tree)*(string*Tree))
  | Leaf of float
```

Comment: What specific part are you stuck on?  SO is not here for write all my code questions

Comment: I clarified the question somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked with [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree), but after reading your requirements

> 1. binary splits
> 2. leafs of float

looking at the example in the [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2009/11/02/awesome-f-decision-trees-part-ii.aspx) and looking at some examples of images using Google search,

I would use:

> type Tree =
>     | Branch of string*(string*Tree)*(string*Tree)
>     | Leaf of float

and match a node using

> match node with
>   | Branch (decision, (v1,l), (v2,r)) ->  // Do something
>   | Leaf value ->  // Do something

And you would compare against the values `v1` or `v2` and choose the appropriate branch, `l` or `r`.

Note: I removed the `()` around `((string*Tree)*(string*Tree))` so that you could use

`Branch (decision, (v1,l), (v2,r))` instead of
`Branch (decision, ((v1,l), (v2,r)))`

Note also that I have not tested or compiled this code, but it should get you started.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction, but what I was really after is given in my answer. Is this the correct way to handle this? I want points to be given fairly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was originally after. A function like this (with "while i>0" logic replaced with whatever you create the tree from) which is based on the tree structure given in the answer from @GuyCoder:

```
type Tree =
| Branch of string*(string*Tree)*(string*Tree)
| Leaf of float

let rec buildTree i =
    if i<1 then Leaf 1.
    else Branch ("Branch", ("Condition1", (buildTree (i-1))), ("Condition1", (buildTree (i-1))))
```